# $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X$ a discrete random variable with three modalities $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$, and $Y$ a discrete random variable with three modalities $(y_1, y_2, y_3)$. True or False : Suppose $X \not= Y$. If the three modalities of $X$ are equiprobable and the three modalities of $Y$ are also equiprobable, then $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

I think it is true, because the joint probability distribution of $X$ and $Y$ can be equal to $\frac{1}{9}$ everywhere, $P(X=x_i, Y=y_i)=\frac{1}{9}$, but the real answer is false. Why is that?

Comment: By "modalities" you mean, those are the values the variables can take?  But then what is to prevent $X=Y$?  The fact that they "can be" independent does not imply that they actually are independent.

Comment: Yes, the values the variables an take.

Comment: As lulu noted, you have shown the answer is "sometimes true," but I think by considering $X = Y$, you will see the answer is "in general, false."

Comment: @lulu Yes, the question says that $X \not = Y$. Just forgot to say it in the question.

Comment: Ok, so suppose $x_i=y_i$ and that $X=x_1\iff Y=x_3$, $X=x_2\iff Y=x_2$ and $X=x_3\iff Y=y_1$.

Comment: @lulu Can you make a full answer to explain why it is False?

Comment: My last comment is a full answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a counterexample of a specific joint probability distribution of $X$ and $Y$ that satisfies the conditions (in particular, equiprobability of the marginal distributions):

\begin{align*}
\begin{array}{c|ccc|c}
\vphantom{\dfrac{1}{6}}&y_1&y_2&y_3&\sum\\
\hline
x_1&\dfrac{1}{6}&\dfrac{1}{6}&0&\dfrac{1}{3}\\
x_2&\dfrac{1}{6}&\dfrac{1}{6}&0&\dfrac{1}{3}\\
x_3&0&0&\dfrac{1}{3}&\dfrac{1}{3}\\
\hline
\sum&\dfrac{1}{3}&\dfrac{1}{3}&\dfrac{1}{3}&1
\end{array}
\end{align*}

Clearly, $X$ and $Y$ are not identical (if $X$ takes on the value of $x_1$, then $Y$ may still take two distinct values $y_1$ and $y_2$). Yet, they are not independent because, for example, $$\mathbb P(X=x_1\text{ and }Y=y_1)=\frac{1}{6}\neq\frac{1}{9}=\mathbb P(X=x_1)\mathbb P(Y=y_1).$$